# Should parents be worshipped before the gods?

Tags: gods, rituals, worship, parents

I do know that parents are like gods to their children. I have seen families where some worship God first then parents but also vice versa. Which one is the correct way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Scriptures,**i believe**, are indicating that **parents should be worshiped before the Gods.**

To prove this we can resort to the Pancha Maha Yajnas which are among the compulsory duties of every householder(Grihasta).

Every Scriptures,including the Manu Smriti, mention about  these 5 great sacrifices :

> The pañca-mahā yajñas are the daily duties to be performed by the
>   householder for the rest of his life. They are the requiting of the
>   spiritual debts (ṛṇas) occurred through taking birth on this planet:—
>
> **1. Pitṛ ṛṇa — pitṛ yajña =** debt to the parents and ancestors, requited through honouring parents and performing their cremation and the
>   memorial rites for them and the ancestors after death.
>
> **2. Deva-ṛṇa — deva-yajña =** debt to the gods requited by performing the homa and other periodic ceremonies in their honour.
>
> **3. Ṛṣī-ṛṇa — brahma-yajña =** debt to the sages requited through study and teaching.
>
> **4. Manuṣya-ṛṇa — manuṣya-yajña =** debt to society requited through feeding of strangers and caring for their needs.
>
> **5. Bhūta-ṛṇa — bhūta-yajña =** debt to the environment and other creatures by ensuring their food supply.

Now,from the order of the sacrifices one can see **that the ancestors including the parents are to be satisfied first**,then comes the Devas,Rishis and the rest.

Although this applies to the deceased parents but still **it indicates that parents should come before the Devas or Gods when that order matters.**

The importance of Pita(father) ,Mata(mother) and the Guru(tecaher,preceptor) are immense in the Sanatana Dharma.

For example,the Manu Smriti says:

> 2.227. That trouble (and pain) which the parents undergo on 
>   the birth of (their) children, cannot be compensated even in a hundred
>   years.
>
> 2.228. Let him always do what is agreeable to those (two) 
>   and always (what may please) his teacher; when those three are
>   pleased, he obtains all (those rewards
>   which) austerities (yield).
>
> 2.229. Obedience towards those three is declared to be the 
>   best (form of) austerity; let him not perform other meritorious acts
>   without their permission.
>
> 2.230. For they are declared to be the three worlds, they the three (principal) orders, they the three Vedas, and they the three sacred
>   fires
>
> 2.231. The father, forsooth, is stated to be the Garhapatya fire, the mother the Dakshinagni, but the teacher the Ahavaniya fire; this triad
>   of fires is most venerable
>
> **2.234. All duties have been fulfilled by him who honours those three; but to him who honours them not, all rites remain fruitless.**
>
> 2.237. By (honouring) these three all that ought to be done 
>   by man, is accomplished; **that is clearly the highest duty, every other
>   (act) is a subordinate duty.**

[image]

[image]

The highlighted portion in the very last verse(2.237) clearly indicates **that the worship of parents should precede that of Gods.**

In fact,not only the parents,in all Hindu traditions, the Guru is also worshiped first before the Gods.

Comment: Can you kindly give exact verse number reference of a scripture - which lists the five mentioned above: "Pitṛ ṛṇa — pitṛ yajña;Deva-ṛṇa — deva-yajña ; Ṛṣī-ṛṇa — brahma-yajña ; Manuṣya-ṛṇa — manuṣya-yajña ;Bhūta-ṛṇa — bhūta-yajña" ?

Comment: Thr are many such scriptures. Manu Smriti itself talks about the 5 great sacrifices. Those are those sacrifices. I will hv to search for the exact verse no though. @zaxebo1

Comment: Great answer.Should be kept constantly on the home page.

Comment: But keeping it constantly on the home page is no possible :D @Partha

Comment: But should be tried somehow.Those who do not worship parents just have no right to talk about dharma.

Comment: Yes, that is true ... @Partha